# Exponential and Functions

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I am having some trouble solving this exercise.

I have a family of fuctions defined by $y=k\cdot 2^{2px - 1}-3$
The function and graphic is $f(x)=2^{2x-2}-3$
And two dots of the ghaphic f: A (2;1) and B (1;-2)

I need to prove that $f(x)=2^{2x-2}-3$

Please, give me a hint.
Thank you :)

Comment: Do you mean $f(x) = k\cdot 2^{2px - 1}-3$...?

Comment: yes. That's right

Comment: thank you for editing that. It looks less messie.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nudge.

From your two points you get:

$$1 = k \cdot 2^{4p-1} - 3$$
$$-2 = k \cdot 2^{2p-1} - 3$$

Consolidate the constants:

$$4 = k \cdot 2^{4p-1}$$
$$1 = k \cdot 2^{2p-1}$$

This implies

$$k \cdot 2^{4p-1} = 4k \cdot 2^{2p-1}$$

Divide both sides by $k \cdot 2^{2p-1}$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make equations with given data.

Point A has coordinates $x=2, y=1$, so if it belongs to the function's graph, the function equation is satistied by those coordinates:
$$f(2) = k\cdot 2^{2p\cdot 2 - 1}-3 = 1$$
Similary for point B you have $x=1, y=-2$ satisfy $y=f(x)$, hence
$$f(1) = k\cdot 2^{2p\cdot 1 - 1}-3 = -2$$

Add $3$ to both sides of both equations and you have:

$$k\cdot 2^{2p\cdot 2 - 1} = 4$$
$$k\cdot 2^{2p\cdot 1 - 1} = 1$$

Separate $(-1)$ from exponents:
$$k\cdot \left(2^{2p\cdot 2} / 2 \right) = 4$$
$$k\cdot \left(2^{2p\cdot 1} / 2 \right) = 1$$

Now use the known relation of exponents: $(A^B)^C = A^{B C}$:
$$k\cdot \left((2^p)^4 / 2 \right) = 4$$
$$k\cdot \left((2^p)^2 / 2 \right) = 1$$

Divide them side-wise:
$$\frac {k\cdot \left((2^p)^4 / 2 \right)}{k\cdot \left((2^p)^2 / 2 \right)} = \frac 41$$

$$\frac {(2^p)^4}{(2^p)^2} = \frac 41$$
$$(2^p)^2 = 4 = 2^2$$
$$2^p = 2 = 2^1$$
$$p = 1$$

Now recall the equation for point B:
$$k\cdot 2^{2p\cdot 1 - 1}-3 = -2$$

Plug $p=1$ to get:
$$k\cdot 2^{2\cdot 1\cdot 1 - 1} = 1$$
$$k\cdot 2^{2 - 1} = 1$$
$$k\cdot 2^1 = 1$$
$$k = 1/2$$

Finally
$$\begin{align} f(x) && = k\cdot 2^{2px - 1}-3 \\
&& = \frac 12 \cdot 2^{2x - 1}-3 \\
&& = 2^{2x - 1 - 1}-3 \\
&& = 2^{2x - 2}-3 \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!
I did with other values too to see if I learned.